# How to define two rule using plink in Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I will demo in a simple example, I have two files named a.map and a.ped which are plink format. I want to use two commands, first transform to bfile format, and second transform to raw format.

My files: a.map, a.ped:

```
> $ cat a.map

1 snp1 0 1
1 snp2 0 2
1 snp3 0 3


> $ cat a.ped 

1 1 0 0 1  0  1 1  2 2  1 1
1 2 0 0 2  0  2 2  0 0  2 1
1 3 1 2 1  2  0 0  1 2  2 1
2 1 0 0 1  0  1 1  2 2  0 0
2 2 0 0 2  2  2 2  2 2  0 0
2 3 1 2 1  2  1 1  2 2  1 1
```

First command:

```
plink --file a --out b
```

I get four files:
b.bed b.bam b.fam b.log

```
(base) [dengfei@localhost plink-test]$ ls b*
b.bed  b.bim  b.fam  b.log
```

Second command:

```
 plink --bfile b --out c --recodeA
```

I get two files:
c.log  c.raw

Here is my question:
In the first command, plink use `--out` to generate `b.bim, b.bed,b.fam`, but I can't use the name in second command in Snakemake.

My fist Snakefile:

```
rule bfile:
params:
    a1 = "a",
    a2 = "b"
shell:"plink --file {params.a1} --out {params.a2}"
```

It runs well.

```
    (base) [dengfei@localhost plink-test]$ snakemake -s test1.py 
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   bfile
    1

rule bfile:
    jobid: 0

PLINK v1.90b6.5 64-bit (13 Sep 2018)           www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/
(C) 2005-2018 Shaun Purcell, Christopher Chang   GNU General Public License v3
Logging to b.log.
Options in effect:
  --file a
  --out b

63985 MB RAM detected; reserving 31992 MB for main workspace.
.ped scan complete (for binary autoconversion).
Performing single-pass .bed write (3 variants, 6 people).
--file: b.bed + b.bim + b.fam written.
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
```

When I add another rule in snakemake to run the second command, something goes wrong, my Snakefile:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "c.log","c.raw"
rule bfile:
    params:
        a1 = "a",
        a2 = "b"
    shell:"plink --file {params.a1} --out {params.a2}"
rule cfile:
    params:
        aa1 = "b",
    aa2 = "c"
    shell:"plink --bfile {params.aa1} --out {params.aa2} --recodeA"
```

It shows c.log and c.raw Missing input

```
MissingInputException in line 1 of /home/dengfei/test/snakemake/plink-test/test1.py:
Missing input files for rule all:
c.log
c.raw
```

I don't know how to connect the two rules. Any suggestions will be great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake uses `input` and `output` files to identify dependencies in the workflow, and they are missing in your rules. Define `input` and `output` files for both rules `bfile` and `cfile`, and then define final file (or expected outfiles) of workflow in `rule all`.

```
rule all:
    input:
        "c.log","c.raw"

rule bfile:
    input:
        "input files of rule bfile here"
    output:
        "output files of rule bfile here"
    params:
        a1 = "a",
        a2 = "b"
    shell:
        "plink --file {params.a1} --out {params.a2}"

rule cfile:
    input:
        "rule bfile outfiles"
    output:
        "c.log", "c.raw"
    params:
        aa1 = "b",
        aa2 = "c"
    shell:
        "plink --bfile {params.aa1} --out {params.aa2} --recodeA"
```

I would recommend working through [snakemake tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thank you, I know the answer with your help. I should use the `input` and `output` in both `rule`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of JeeYem, the right code is:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "c.log","c.raw"

rule bfile:
    input:
        "a.map","a.ped"
    output:
        "b.bed","b.bim","b.fam"
    params:
        a1 = "a",
        a2 = "b"
    shell:
        "plink --file {params.a1} --out {params.a2}"

rule cfile:
    input:
        "b.bed","b.bim","b.fam"
    output:
        "c.log", "c.raw"
    params:
        aa1 = "b",
        aa2 = "c"
    shell:
        "plink --bfile {params.aa1} --out {params.aa2} --recodeA"
```

And I run snakemake, It generate the result I wanted:

```
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   bfile
    1   cfile
    3

rule bfile:
    input: a.map, a.ped
    output: b.bed, b.bim, b.fam
    jobid: 2

PLINK v1.90b6.5 64-bit (13 Sep 2018)           www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/
(C) 2005-2018 Shaun Purcell, Christopher Chang   GNU General Public License v3
Logging to b.log.
Options in effect:
  --file a
  --out b

63985 MB RAM detected; reserving 31992 MB for main workspace.
.ped scan complete (for binary autoconversion).
Performing single-pass .bed write (3 variants, 6 people).
--file: b.bed + b.bim + b.fam written.
Finished job 2.
1 of 3 steps (33%) done

rule cfile:
    input: b.bed, b.bim, b.fam
    output: c.log, c.raw
    jobid: 1

PLINK v1.90b6.5 64-bit (13 Sep 2018)           www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/
(C) 2005-2018 Shaun Purcell, Christopher Chang   GNU General Public License v3
Note: --recodeA flag deprecated.  Use 'recode A ...'.
Logging to c.log.
Options in effect:
  --bfile b
  --out c
  --recode A

63985 MB RAM detected; reserving 31992 MB for main workspace.
3 variants loaded from .bim file.
6 people (4 males, 2 females) loaded from .fam.
3 phenotype values loaded from .fam.
Using 1 thread (no multithreaded calculations invoked).
Before main variant filters, 4 founders and 2 nonfounders present.
Calculating allele frequencies... done.
Total genotyping rate is 0.777778.
3 variants and 6 people pass filters and QC.
Among remaining phenotypes, 3 are cases and 0 are controls.  (3 phenotypes are
missing.)
--recode A to c.raw ... done.
Finished job 1.
2 of 3 steps (67%) done

localrule all:
    input: c.log, c.raw
    jobid: 0

Finished job 0.
3 of 3 steps (100%) done
```